# DataGridView combobox cell event in c#

Tags: c#

I want to display a message when items in DataGridViewComboBox has been changed. I am able to perform it partially by taking help of datagridview CellbeginEdit event and CellEndEdit event but that is not up to mark. I want it as it happen in combobox selection change event.

I had google it for solving but not get appropriate help.

Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: Are you using winform? What have you tried?

Comment: Yes am using windows form. for performing same task I used cell end event and cell begin event of datagridview.

Comment: is the combobox bind to datagridview?

Comment: Yes i had bind datagridview combo box by using propery of datagridview.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use EditingControlShowing event for it

```
private void grvList_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
             if (grvList.Columns[grvList.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Name.Equals("routing_ID"))
                {
                    ComboBox cmbprocess = e.Control as ComboBox;
                    cmbprocess.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(grvcmbProcess_SelectedIndexChanged);
                }
        }


 private void grvcmbProcess_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox cmbprocess = (ComboBox)sender;
            if (cmbprocess.SelectedValue != null)
            {
               /// Your Code goes here
            }

        }
```

this is only an example program to show how to do it

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I am going to use it. If i got any problem then I will let you know it.