# How to detect if Combobox selection is changed by user

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a DataGridColumn and it has a Combobox CellTemplate:

```
                 <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox Name="DataItems"
                                      Width="120"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                      DisplayMemberPath="Value"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding RowData.Row.DataDictionary}"
                                      SelectedValue="{Binding RowData.Row.Data}"
                                      SelectedValuePath="Key" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
```

I need to detect if the *user* has changed the *initial value* of the combobox.

If I use the SelectionChanged event, it fires every time (even at creation).

The view is created dinamically so I can't really use a *bool* value to check if it is just created or been altered.

What event or binding should I use to detect if the *user* changed the selection and not the initial loading happened?

Comment: Is it possible for the application to change the value? If not you can have a bool set to true when SelectionChanged is thrown. Or are you wanting to distinguish between the user action and code action?

Comment: Only the user supposed to change the value _after the initial loading_. So I guess I should detect user interaction only.

Comment: Okay, in that case do you set the selectedindex during loading? If you don't set the index during loading you can use the selectedindexchanged handler and check if he old value was -1 (the default index if nothing is set) if you do however set a selected index during load, you could have a bool value within your class "firstTime" or something that effect that you can use to bypass the action in Selectionchanged during loading then possibly have the handler un-register itself after the use changes the initial value.

Comment: Maybe this has the answer for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530596/datagridview-combobox-cell-event-in-c-sharp

Comment: @CalebB I don't set the selected index, the selected value is set by binding, so there is no -1 for selected index. Also It doesn't have SelectedIndexChanged, it is a WPF control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple solution for me is using the ***PropertyChanged*** event.

It has 2 advantages:

- It complies with MVVM (I don't mix the view with the viewmodel)
- PropertyChanged is fired only *after the construction is done* (which basically means that only the explicit use gets notified)

Here is the code:

```
public DataItem FirstDataItem
   {
          get 
          { 
          return firstDataItem; 
          }
          set
          {
            firstDataItem= value;
            if (FirstDataItem!= null)
              FirstDataItem.PropertyChanged += (x, y) =>
              {
                if (y.PropertyName =="Data" )
                  DoSomething();
              };
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

To me, I will use OneWayToSource binding. And with your code behind handle, you may know: your source is changed by user or your logical processes.

SelectionChanged will be fired after SelectedValue is changed. It does not care how SelectedValue can be updated. When the control is created, wpf resolved SelectedValue by getting action from source. With OneWayToSource binding, SelectedValue will be not updated by code behind after that time.

In your situation, code should be like this:

```
 public event EventHandler SelectedChangedByUser;
 public event EventHandler SelectedChangedByCode;

 public object SelectedValue
 {
   get
   {
         return _selectedVaue;
   }

   set
   {
    if(value != _selectedValue)
    {
        _selectValue = value;
        if(NotifyPropertyChanged != null)
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedValue");
        }   

        if(SelectedChangedByUser != null)
        {
            SelectedChangedByUser(this, new EventArgs());
        }
      }
    }
 }


  public void UpdateSelectedValue(object value)
  {
   if(value != _selectedValue)
   {
    _selectValue = value;   
    if(SelectedChangedByCode != null)
    {
        SelectedChangedByCode(this, new EventArgs());
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: How would I know if the user changes the source?

Comment: Source is in code behind, user only can modify UI. ^^

Comment: How could I tell if the selection is changed by the user? SelectionChanged fires when the control is created and when the user click and changes another item. I can't tell what was the modification source. Also, my binding has to be TwoWay.